# jBPM How to implement Decision

Tags: jbpm

I´m new on JBPM (version 3) and i´m trying to implement (unsuccessfully) a Decision.

I realized that i must do something like this:

Cenario 1:

```
<decision name="XPTO Decision" expression="#{contextInstance.variables['XPTO Decision']}">
 <transition name="To ActionA" to="ActionA"/>
 <transition name="To ActionB" to="ActionB"/>
 <transition to="ActionA"/>
 </decision>
```

Or:

Cenario 2:

```
 <decision name="XPTO Decision" >
 <transition name="To ActionA" to="ActionA"/>
 <transition name="To ActionA" to="ActionA"/>
 <transition to="ActionA">
 <condition expression="#contextInstance.variables['XPTO Decision'] ge 5"/>
 </transition>
 </decision>
```

Or:

Cenario 3:

```
 <decision name="XPTO Decision" >
 <handler class="bla.bli.MyDecisionHandler"/>
 <transition name="To ActionA" to="ActionA"/>
 <transition name="To ActionB" to="ActionB"/>
 <transition to="ActionA"/>
 </decision>
```

I have done something like this, but my decision already goes to the same action (ActionB).

I don´t have sure about how this decision work. Looking for cenario 2 i believe that is something like

"if  variable XPTO Decision ge (greates or equals(?)) 5 then Action A
  else Action B"." Is that right?

And...  How the cenario 3 works??? How can the handler decide which Action is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
<decision name="XPTODecision">
    <description>
        XPTO decision.
    </description>
    <transition to="XX" name="xx">
        <condition> #{ body.Success} </condition>
    </transition>
    <transition to="YY" name="yy">
        <condition> <![CDATA[#{body.NumberXX <= body.Maximum && theBody.Success}]]></condition>
    </transition>
</decision>

<node name="XX">
...
</node>

<node name="YY">
...
</node>
```

Answer (score 1):

So what is this: #contextInstance.variables['XPTO Decision'] ge 5 ??
In which language that kind of expression works? You should take a look at the jBPM3 documentation where the conditional node is explained. In the case that contextInstance is a process variable that you are trying to evaluate it should look something like:
${contextInstance.variables['asd'] > 5} and that evaluation will return "true" or "false" which means that you need to have two transitions, one called "true" and the other "false"

I'm pretty sure that you don't have a contextInstance Object to evaluate, so if you want to evaluate a process variable directly try with: ${asd > 5}
Cheers

Comment: I saw in some page the 'ge' expression. One of the problem is the one you said, i didn't have a contextInstance Object to evaluate. Thanks. (When i have 15 of reputation i will vote your answer).